# How to convert Geom object from PostGis in R in latitude and longitude?

Tags: r, postgresql, geolocation, coordinates, postgis

I have a database that has "location" attribute and it is saved as geom object and looks like this: `0101000020E6100000000000603D1D5EC0000000A06D424740`

Is there a way to extract coordinates from it in R? These values are loaded in R as strings. Also it gave a warning:

```
Warning message:
In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type geometry (id:18832) in column 2)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe more relevant for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`rgeos`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) functions? One option would be reading WKT directly from the database (using [`ST_AsText`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html))...

```
SELECT ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000000000603D1D5EC0000000A06D424740');
                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(-120.456871032715 46.518970489502)
(1 Zeile)
```

In R, using [`readWKT`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-28/topics/RGEOS%20WKT%20Functions) you can then extract the coordinate pair:

```
> readWKT("POINT(-120.456871032715 46.518970489502)")
SpatialPoints:
          x        y
1 -120.4569 46.51897
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Another option would be to read *x,y* directly from the database using [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html):

```
 SELECT ST_X('0101000020E6100000000000603D1D5EC0000000A06D424740'),
        ST_Y('0101000020E6100000000000603D1D5EC0000000A06D424740');
       st_x        |      st_y       
-------------------+-----------------
 -120.456871032715 | 46.518970489502
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that! However, I did the same as ST_X and ST_Y using postgres and than loaded my table in Rstudio.

Comment: @Nata there are certainly a million ways to get coordinate pairs from geometries.. but I guess this one for your needs will suffice. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that [Jim Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275388/jim-jones) answer used mainly postgis and not R.
The SF package allows for the conversion of Well Known Binary (WKB) to a simple features column (sfc), which in turn can be converted to coordinates.
[st_as_sfc documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_as_sfc.html)
code:

```r
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
wkb = structure(list("0101000020E6100000000000603D1D5EC0000000A06D424740"), class = "WKB")
st_as_sfc(wkb,EWKB = TRUE) %>% st_coordinates()
#>           X        Y
#> 1 -120.4569 46.51897
```